# Apply for F1 from home country after B1 extension

Tags: b1-b2-visas, visa-extensions, f1-visas

I am trying to analyse the risk factor here.

I recently came back to India after my 5 months stay in US on B1 visa. I initially got 2 months stamp on entering US, then again applied for 3 months extension from USCIS.

I am planning to apply for F1 after 2 months from India. I have received an admit from one of the US universities.

What are my chances of getting F1? I am concerned because of my previous visa extension and not sure if applying again for a F1 visa in short duration will create suspicion.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

1. What do you mean by suspicion? They will obviously ask about your previous visa and trip.
2. As long as you have valid reasons and no mal-intent in staying back in the US, and can clearly explain what you were doing in the US, prior to your F1, you are going to be fine.
3. I know of friends who have gone for visit to US; check out universities, stay with family/ friends, tourism, some business/ work related trip. So, a following F1 should not be an issue.
4. As long as the connection and reasoning between your B1 trip + extension & your new F1 has sound reasoning you should have no issues.
5. Bottom line, as long as they do not perceive some kind of flight risk/ mal intent in your interview conversation you should be good.

PS: Additional note: Since, you did not state what you were doing during your B1 trip and whether you applied for F1 only to make another stay.. I am suspicious because you are not clear or afraid/ hiding something?

If you can't be clear in the head about the above or speak with conviction, you might arouse suspicion with the consular officer.

Comment: "I know of friends" is not necessarily valid - I know of people who overstayed illegally but managed to get away with it, don't recommend copying them ;)
Also, if you want to clarify something (eg your point 6 and point 1) - do so as a comment BEFORE answering, ideally, in case his clarification nullifies your answer.

Comment: None of these friends or OP did anything illegal or overstayed. The reason it is relevant is I know of people who got F1s after their B1 trips involved the above mentioned activities.